# Calculate surface Integral with sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8CaP.png)
I tried spherical coordinates but the expression was very complex. Can someone help me?

Compute  $∫∫_S$**F**$⋅$**N**$dS$,  where  $F(x,y,z)=2yz$**i**$+(tan^{−1}(xz))$**j**$+e^{xy}$**k**  and N is an outward normal vector S, where S is the surface of sphere  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

P/s: Sorry for my poor English

Comment: **Hint**: Use the Gauss-Divergence Theorem.

Comment: The divergence of the vector field is zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Gauss divergence theorem $$∫∫∫_V\mathrm{div}F dV=∫∫_SF\cdot NdS,$$ and note that $\mathrm{div}F=0$.